# What's the difference between standardization and global contrast normalization? (Image preprocessing)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I'm trying to understand the article located [here](https://caglarift6266.wordpress.com/)

I have 2 questions:

1. What's the difference between standardization and global contrast normalization?
   To the best of my understanding, I think they mean the same thing in which we subtracts each pixel of an image with the global mean and divides by the global standard deviation.
2. What's the purpose of them in machine learning or feature extraction topic?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) It is not completely clear from the post you shared, but it looks like standardization is normalizing each image column separately (while global contrast normalization does this over all pixels in the image). My guess is that both use the Standardize function from this [pylearn2 documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/library/datasets.html) but the first step has the two global flags set to false, while the second step sets them to true.

2.) Normalization is a fairly standard step in machine learning/feature extraction. It basically attempts to convert data into a common input space, and can at least partially deal with external sources of data variation like illumination levels. A good start would be to read the Wikipedia article on [feature scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling).

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I'm learning pylearn2 and was confused by these two functions.

I got this answer from the pylearn2 group.
"GCN computes the mean and std across features, independently for each example.
Standardize computes the mean and std across the examples of the dataset, for each feature."